# How do I run the RowDataBound method in the onClick method below?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView as follow

```
`<asp:GridView ID="gvSearchAll" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
     OnPageIndexChanging="searchAll_PageIndexChanging" 
     onrowdatabound="OnRowDataBound">
         <Columns>
              <asp:BoundField DataField="A" HeaderText="A"/>
              <asp:BoundField DataField="B" HeaderText="B"/>
              <asp:BoundField DataField="C" HeaderText="C" />
              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:CheckBox ID="RowSelector" runat="server" onclick="checkRadioBtn(this);" />
                  </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>                  
         </Columns>          
 </asp:GridView>`
```

OnRowDataBound on CodeBehind, I have the following:

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {               
           e.Row.Cells[3].Attributes.Add("onclick", string.Format("DisplayDetails('{0}');", e.Row.RowIndex + 1));
           e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "onMouseOver('" + (e.Row.RowIndex + 1) + "')";
           e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "onMouseOut('" + (e.Row.RowIndex + 1) + "')";
        }        

    }
```

Now what I wanted actually, was the DisplayDetails function to be run when the checkbox is clicked.

```
 function DisplayDetails(row) {
    var gridView = document.getElementById('gvSearchAll');  
    document.getElementById("A").value = gridView.rows[row].cells[1].innerText;
    document.getElementById("B").value = gridView.rows[row].cells[0].innerText;      
}
```

What I wanted to do was, when the checkbox is clicked, I want to fill the particular checkbox's row's A and B column Data to some Text Field.

The onClick function, checkRadioBtn(this), does something else.

Now, Currently, I am executing the Display Details function whenever I click the entire cell of the CheckBox.
What I need, is to execute the DisplayDetails function, in the checkRadioBtn(this) function, but for that I need something like, (this.row_index), which I am unable to figure out how to do.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why you are using checkbox you can easily implement that by using a Link Button

> like this

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvSearchAll" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
     OnPageIndexChanging="searchAll_PageIndexChanging"  >
         <Columns>
              <asp:BoundField DataField="A" HeaderText="A"/>
              <asp:BoundField DataField="B" HeaderText="B"/>
              <asp:BoundField DataField="C" HeaderText="C" />
              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                 <ItemTemplate  >                
                          <asp:LinkButton  ID="RowSelector"  Text="Details"   OnClientClick = "return Details(this)"  runat="server"  CommandName="Select" ></asp:LinkButton>
               </ItemTemplate>                 
         </Columns>          
 </asp:GridView>
```

> on script

```
 function Details(lnk) {
             var row = lnk.parentNode.parentNode;
             var rowIndex = row.rowIndex - 1;
             document.getElementById("A").value = gridView.rows[row].cells[1].innerText;
             document.getElementById("B").value = gridView.rows[row].cells[0].innerText; 
         }
```

Comment: Hi Arun. Thanks for your reply. the requirements was for a checkbox, that is why. The row = lnk.parentNode.parentNode; statement will work on the checkbox too right? I shall give it a try now.

Comment: yup and tell me if it will not work i will try something different

Comment: Hey Arun. works perfectly. Just needed to change rowIndex = row.rowIndex; since the  (-1) gave the value of the previous row. Thanks a lot .

Comment: Laba row.rowIndex - 1; will show current row becouse row index start with 0